# SVN certificate: reject, accept temporarily, or accept permanently?

Tags: svn, certificate

Every time when I run svn update, it asks me : reject, accept temporarily or accept permanently.  Every time I say permanently but nothing changes. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication credentials are stored in the user's local directory. If `svn` has no write access to it, it can't store the password even if you choose "save permanently".

Comment: Indeed, although in about 90% of these situations, it's not write permissions (as they would be from the current user), but the fact the user in question has no home-dir.